# WordPress: How to automatically generate an image's caption

Tags: wordpress

WordPress: How to automatically generate an image's caption (wp-caption-text)? Just as it is now generated from the title of the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a filter to update the caption or any other image attribute when the image is being uploaded.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/attachment_fields_to_save